# Wrong Width in IE in Report Server

Tags: firefox, ssrs-2008, internet-explorer-10, web-deployment

Goal:
To make the width of the report to be similiar for Internet Explorer and Firefox in the website in report server `(http://myserver/reportserver).`

Problem:
Displaying the report in IE, the width is too short and wrong compare to the original size in Firefox.

What webdevelopment code in IE do I need to change to make it similar for Firefox and IE?

Information:
*The report is located in a server and the customer use their client computer to get access to the reports. The user use their own IE browser and type in the URL address that is the server's ipnumber with "reportserver" `"(http://myserver01/reportserver)"`

*The server's web reader is IE 10. No firefox in the server.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.

The code "" is same for FF and IE. In order to make it width for IE you have to change the value into "width: 150%" instead of ""width: 100%;"

The answer is it answering but I still need to return.